# regarding swp files and same file opened in different vnc

Tags: linux, vnc, gvim

I have different VNCs at work and many times, i forget to save or close some files opened in gvim. Later, I'll open up the same file in another VNC. Though it'll tell me that it is already opened somewhere else because of the .swp file. But, I may have some critical unsaved work in the former VNC.

Is there any way to find out in which all VNCs, I've the file opened??
Please help...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this will get you enough information to identify the VNC because I don't have a VNC setup to test it with, but it might help.

Note the name of the swap file that gvim says already exists. Use `fuser` to find the process ID (PID) of the gvim instance that has the swap file opened. Then use `ps -Hf` to find that process ID and its parent(s). The top-most parent of the gvim process may have enough information in the command line to identify the VNC.

For example, say gvim tells you that the swap file /var/tmp/somefile.swp already exists. Find the PID of the other gvim instance by executing

```
fuser /var/tmp/somefile.swp
```

Say the PID is 12345. Execute this command to find more about that process and its parent(s):

```
ps -Hfe | less +/12345
```

Alternatively, the environment of the gvim instance that has the swap file opened might have a variable that identifies the VNC. Say that gvim has PID 12345. The following command will let you explore the environment of that process.

```
tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/12345/environ | less
```